# Execute OS specific script in node / Grunt

Tags: node.js, shell, operating-system, gruntjs

I have a Grunt task which executes .cmd file on the local machine to do its thing. I need to use this task on the CI server, which is a Linux machine. I have the relevant .sh (shell script for Linux) for that. I need a way to execute these two without changing my Gruntfile.

Currently I have to change my Gruntfile to make it work locally for windows and remote file uses .sh.

Any solution to do same is welcome. Detecting underlying OS? Or a way to call same command which internally calls the OS specific command?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could take advantage of node's [process.platform](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform):

> process.platform
> What platform you're running on: 'darwin', 'freebsd', 'linux', 'sunos' or 'win32'
>
> console.log('This platform is ' + process.platform);

Then within the code, optionally add the file extensions based on that:

```
if (process.platform === "win32") {
    ext = ".cmd";
} else {
    ext = ".sh";
}
```

Comment: `win32` = windows; `darwin` = Mac; `linux` = linux. No idea what the other 2 are for. Anyone know why Mac is referred to as 'darwin'?

Comment: @DanT because of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system) google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Using grunt-shell or any other shell command tool, take advantage of the similarities between win and *nix shells, particularly `||`. The first `cmd` will fail on *nix and fallback to `sh`:

```
    shell: {
        options: {
            stderr: false,
            failOnError: true
        },
        command: 'cmd command.cmd || sh command.sh'
    }
```

Comment: Travis CI run sh command, but [**I get a warning and build failed**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaPelicanTest/jobs/348635075#L721). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, try flip them around?